# How does animus have the meaning of ill will?

Tags: etymology

*animus* has the etymology of "breath, life", just like *animate*.

How does animus have the meaning of ill will?

Comment: I'm not sure you're looking at the same [etymology I'm looking at](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=animus). It already had that secondary meaning in Latin, cf. *animosity*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/animus) shows the etymology of *animus* to be:

> 1810–20;  < Latin:  mind, spirit, courage, passion, wrath; akin to anima

So its etymology is not in fact what you suggest, but more along the lines of "passion" and "wrath", which easily leads to the idea of "ill will".

Comment: But why not good will?

Comment: I guess the Romans thought that when you got "passionate", it was usually because you were in a bad mood?

Comment: Because it comes from a PIE root 'ane-' which means 'wind' and therefore 'breathe' or 'exhale' - by extension giving the meaning of temper, passion and wrath. And of course the same root meaning allows the other interpretation of 'life'.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the various meanings of Latin **animus** (substantive), and **animosus** (adjective) ; both can bear a *positive* aspect (being full of life, or courage) and a *negative* one (violence).

Animosity comes from the French *animosité*, which retains only the second mood, and probably influenced the English meaning of "animus"

However, "animal" means etymologically "gifted with life", by opposition of vegetation supposed in the past to be inert (hence : vegetative). One more mistake from Aristotle.